Ubuntu 24.04: "Hardware does not pass checks" error with Secure Boot Enabled
I'm facing a "Hardware does not pass checks" error message after installing Ubuntu 24.04 on my Dell Precision T1700. UEFI and secure boot is enabled on my system. I've tried troubleshooting steps, checking boot and BIOS settings, updating firmware In settings and security the image shows hardware does not pass checks, Secure boot is active. Does anyone have experience with this issue or can suggest potential solutions? Any advice on how to troubleshoot this further would be greatly appreciated.Image shows little information on hardware does not pass checks.
System: Dell Precision T1700
Processor: Intel Core i7-4790
RAM: 8GB
BIOS: UEFI
SSD 518GB
Secure Boot: Enabled
I have been trying to install linux and Ubuntu for weeks.
does this "hardware does not pass checks" mean I cannot use this OS long term before is crashes due to incompatibility. If I cannot use Ubuntu 24.04, what Linux Distro would work?
Please can you help, I am a newbie, only three weeks.

It's testing your Precision T1700 for hardware security deficiencies. Most "Hardware does not pass checks" fails are irrelevant. It's NOT testing to see if Ubuntu is compatible. Ubuntu is fully compatible with most hardware, even hardware with security deficiencies. If you want a definite answer, edit your question above to share your output.

It was glitchy and unstable, After weeks of trying to install Ubuntu, and multiple distros, I have given up for now.

Thank you for responding. all the best.

If you or anyone can help, I have a Dell Pression T1700 and a Lenovo Ideacentre AIO 300-23ISU

Next time you try, open a question detailing "glitchy and unstable". A link to a clear, stable, readable video showing the issue might help. More detail = better help.

I tried to leave newer Ubuntu ASK, sometimes no matter how I word the title of content, tags etc I am unable to post. I am so new to this. Example: search bars will not allow text to search, little things like that that make it impossible to go forward with an install not working as it should. I will try and leave a better question, Thanks.

Sorry, I am new to Ubuntu and Linux. I have moved on, however I will add logs and detailed information next time.

Thank you, as a new comer, It is a steep learning curve. I will try to explain in more detail in future.
